# Extracting specific rows in a CSV file based on a certain prefix

Tags: c#, csv

I am attempting to read multiple CSV files in a directory, process and filter these appropriately based on a specific prefix using c#. I then want to write each row to a new CSV file that contains that prefix. The CSV header remains the same.

For example, I have a CSV file before processing as such:

[image: CSV before processing]

If there is a prefix in a row starting with BAK as an example I want to extract all rows of data to a new CSV file that have that prefix, so my CSV would then look like this. Note that the prefix may not always be in the same place.

CSV after processing:

[image: CSV after processing]

I have looked at other questions and answers and feel these do not address my question.

What I have so far (C#):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string sourceDirectory = @"C:\temp\csvfiles\";
    var csvFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string currentFile in csvFiles) {
        //How do I read in only the specfic rows that I need containing certain prefixes
    }
}
```

**Edit** 28/10/21

I can now read the multiple files based on the prefix.
When writing the lines to a new csv file its only writing the first line from the first test file in the directory but not the second.

```
try
        {
            string sourceDirectory = @"C:\temp\csvfiles\";
            string path = @"C:\temp\csvfiles\testdone.csv";
   
            var csvFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            
            foreach (string currentFile in csvFiles)
            {
                //How do I read in only the specfic rows that I need containing certain prefixes
                foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(currentFile).Where(m => m.Split(';').Last().Contains("GFP")))
                {
                    // Create and write the csv file
                    File.WriteAllText(path, line.ToString());

                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: 1. You cannot read only rows that contain the prefix because you have to read the row to know what is in it. I suggest you read all rows then filter them using something like `IndexOf` or `Contains`. 2. I advise against writing your own CSV parsing logic as it is trickier than it looks. Use a proven CSV library.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read and parse each row of your input file and then inspect the data to determine if it should be written to the output file.

I don't know how much experience you have parsing CSV files though. There are many available that would make short work of this. May I recommend my own [CsvParser](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/CsvParser)?

Answer (score -1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string sourceDirectory = @"C:\temp\csvfiles\";
        var csvFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string currentFile in csvFiles)
        {
            //How do I read in only the specfic rows that I need containing certain prefixes
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(currentFile).Where(m => m.Split(';').Last().Contains("BAK")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

Update 1: Write all the lines in a new file

```
string sourceDirectory = @"C:\temp\csvfiles\";
        string path = @"C:\temp\csvfiles\testdone.csv";
        var csvFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.csv", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string currentFile in csvFiles)
        {
            //How do I read in only the specfic rows that I need containing certain prefixes
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(currentFile).Where(m => m.Split(';').Last().Contains("bak")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                File.AppendAllText(path, line + Environment.NewLine);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure why this answer has been marked down. This is now filtering on the row that contains only BAK. I just need to now write these specific rows into a new csv file

Comment: see Update 1, adjust contains, whether you like capital letters...